# how to push data into array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Dear All,
I want to push the data into array. i am using flowing code. There are two arrays. one holding keys and 2nd values. i am using flowing code

```
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
     foreach ($arrTemp as $val) 
    {                   
        array_push($arrKeys, $val);
        array_push($arrValues, $data[$val]);                
    }               
}

print_r($arrKeys);
print_r($arrValues);

$arrReturn = array_combine($arrKeys,$arrValues);
```

...................................
and get flowing results of two arrays.

```
Array ( [0] => due_date [1] => flag_code [2] => due_date [3] => flag_code [4] => due_date [6] => flag_code  )


Array ( [0] => 12:04:2011 [1] => 0 [2] => 13:04:2011 [3] => 0 [4] => 14:04:2011 [6] => 0  )
```

when i try to combined the array using array_combined function it only return an array of two values like: `Array (due_date => 14:04:2011 flag => 0)`

how i can get all values in  single array.....!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your have multiple the same array keys. So first it inserts `due_date`, then `flag_code`, then it will try and insert another `due_date` but since this already exists in the array it will overwrite it. Thus the only values left in the array will be the last pair.

The solution is to not have multiple keys that are the same in one array (your `due_date` and `flag_code`)

You could do:

```
foreach ($arrTemp as $val) {                   
    $arrReturn[] = array($val => $data[$val];
}
```

This will give you each set of results keyed in an array like so:

```
$arrReturn[0] = array (due_date => 14:04:2011 flag => 0);
$arrReturn[1] = array (due_date => 14:04:2011 flag => 0);
$arrReturn[2] = array (due_date => 14:04:2011 flag => 0);
...
```

Comment: Please sugges me what i can do. actually i use table column name as array keys and there values as array vlues. some time query return more thn one row. then i face this problm. Please suggest me what i do to over come this problm

Answer (score 1):

```
$ctr = 0;
foreach ($arrKeys as $id => $key) {
  $res_array[$ctr][$key] = $arrValues[$id];
  if ($key == 'flag_code') $ctr++;
  }

print_r($res_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [due_date] => 12:04:2011
            [flag_code] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [due_date] => 13:04:2011
            [flag_code] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [due_date] => 14:04:2011
            [flag_code] => 0
        )

)
```